# Getting compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle

Tags: node.js, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

Getting this error while building apk

A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> com.android.builder.errors.EvalIssueException: compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle

In build.gradle already added
compileSdkVersion cordovaConfig.COMPILE_SDK_VERSION

Also in config.xml file added

Can anyone help me what's the issue

**Ionic Info**

Ionic:

Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.16 (C:\Users\anshi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.9.4
@angular-devkit/build-angular : 12.1.4
@angular-devkit/schematics    : 12.2.18
@angular/cli                  : 12.2.18
@ionic/angular-toolkit        : 4.0.0

Cordova:

Cordova CLI       : 11.0.0
Cordova Platforms : android 11.0.0
Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.2.1, (and 23 other plugins)

Utility:

cordova-res                          : 0.15.4
native-run (update available: 1.7.1) : 1.5.0

System:

Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk)
NodeJS            : v16.13.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
npm               : 6.14.18
OS                : Windows 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install module

```
npm i @ionic/cordova-builders
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the file present in your node_modules?
node_modules/@ionic/cordova-builders/package.json

have you added the builders with: `ng add @ionic/cordova-builders` as per docs? https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ionic/cordova-builders

I don't think this is related to your issue. But the newest version of build tools is 33. cordova-android 11 builds by default for target-SDK-32 I believe. build-tools 26 is for targetSDK-26. I think you should add the newer versions of build tools (or use a lower version of cordova-android)

Comment: yes it was already there path is this                                                                                 
cordova-builders\node_modules\rxjs.node_modules\tslib

Comment: I work with cordova itself, not Ionic, so maybe this is just my ignorance, but that seems like a very different path than the one in the title of your question

Comment: It was not installed properly i have removed and installed it works thanks for your help